# One-One mapping between content types

Tags: entities

I have 2 content types named ***All Events*** and ***Event***. Event as the name is self descriptive it represents an single event (programme). Whereas *All Events* contains additional data related to events, that is not part of any single event.

I need to have a relationship which says '***Featured Event***'. And that relationship is going to be one-one. What would be the best way to select featured event among those events?

To organize this I can create a *field collection* field where each collection represents an event. And again selecting featured content would be question. Having a field in event to make it featured won't work, since 'one-one' wont be respected by the system and user need to take care of it.

Comment: What is your Drupal version?

Answer (score 2):

It's not too clear to me what you are asking but if you want to relate a content-type to another content-type you can use the `Node reference` from the [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module.

You can include a field on your `Event` content type called **Featured Event** and relate it back to the `All Events` content type. Then limit the amount of values to one. Then when you create a node from the `Event` CT, you can relate it to whatever node you want from the `All Events` CT. Vice-versa you can create a relationship through the `All Events` nodes if you wanted to as well.

Then if you wanted you could use the [Corresponding node references](https://www.drupal.org/project/cnr) module to sync up `node to node`. This module will warn you if you have overloading references (more than 1:1 for a node) basically helping keep the integrity of the 1:1 relationship.